# Cypress: access custom defined css property

Tags: reactjs, cypress, chakra-ui

I am building an APP using React + chakra-ui and I am in the process of adding Cypress tests to it, but I am facing a blocker and I was wondering if anyone had faced a similar problem and that could help!

**Problem:**

The test I am trying to pass is to verify that my element contains a CSS property, however, the CSS was generated by Charkaui with their unique syntax (e.g --chakra-scale-x)

My test case is as follow

```
cy.get('MY_ELEMENT')
  .should('be.visible')
  .should('have.css', '--chakra-scale-y', 1);
```

This test gave me the error

```
expected '<div.css-o64oke>' to have CSS property '--chakra-scale-x'
```

even though I can see from inspect element that it does have the following property.

Does anyone know a solution or a workaround for this? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Can you add the HTML of the element along with the CSS applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--chakra-scale-y` is a css variable, which will be applied (probably as a transform) by the browser css engine.

Take a look in the devtools Computed tab (unselect Show all to see just those applied). If a transform shows up, this is what you need to test for.

In the test use `getComputedStyle` to check the value identified above.

```js
cy.get('MY_ELEMENT')
  .then($el => {
    const win = cy.state('window')
    const styles = win.getComputedStyle($el[0])
    const transform = styles.getPropertyValue('transform')
    console.log(transform)
    expect(transform).to.eq(...)
  })
```

---

It looks like you need to check `scaleY`, this is from the chakra library

```js
const transformTemplate = [
  "rotate(var(--chakra-rotate, 0))",
  "scaleX(var(--chakra-scale-x, 1))",
  "scaleY(var(--chakra-scale-y, 1))",
  "skewX(var(--chakra-skew-x, 0))",
  "skewY(var(--chakra-skew-y, 0))",
]
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need! But strangely, I don't see the scale property inside the Computed tab, but if I select 'Show all' and search for --chakra-scale-x, it shows up.

Comment: I am getting`Property 'state' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'` bug from `cy.state('window')`, any ideas why?

Comment: `cy.state('window')` was a shortcut Gleb Bahmutov was using, maybe it's no longer available. You can get the `win` with conventional `cy.window().then(win => {`.

Comment: I'm also looking for a public demo of chakra to experiment with - any ideas?

Comment: Actually, the code you suggest works, instead of `styles.getPropertyValue('transform')`, do `styles.getPropertyValue('--chakra-scale-y');` which matches the computed value.